Tax incidence formula derivation through implicit differentiation
Suppose we levy a specific tax $t$, then, at the new equilibrium, we have
$$
D(p+t)=S(p),
$$
where $D$ is the demand function and $S$ is the supply function. And this makes equilibrium price $p$ is a function of $t$. The incidence formula
$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{D'}{S'-D'},
$$
where $D'=dD(p)/dp$ and $S'=d S(p)/dp$, can be obtained through https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/stantcheva/files/lecture3.pdf.
However, some texts state that we can also obtain this formula through implicit differentiation with respect to $t$. My question is how we can do this.
This is my approach:
\begin{aligned}
&D(p+t)=S(p) \\
\implies &\frac{d D(p+t)}{d (p+t)} \frac{d (p+t)}{d t} = \frac{d S(p)}{d p)} \frac{d p}{d t} \\
\implies &D'(p+t)(\frac{d p}{d t}+1)=S'(p) \frac{d p}{d t}
\end{aligned}
It seems that only when $D'(p+t) = D'(p)$, I can obtain the same tax incidence formula. But is $D'(p+t) = D'(p)$ TRUE?
p.s. I know Is there an intuitive explanation for the tax incidence formula from elasticity? provides a good derivation way but it is still not through implicit differentiation.

Ah...I think it is certain that $\frac{d D(p+t)}{d (p+t)} = \frac{d D(u)}{d u}$...

The implicit function theorem is handy here.
Rewrite the equilibrium condition as
\begin{equation}
F(p,t):=S(p)-D(p+t) = 0
\end{equation}
Using the implicit function theorem, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt} = -\frac{\partial F/\partial t}{\partial F/\partial p} 
= -\frac{-D'}{S'-D'}
= \frac{D'}{S'-D'} \;,
\end{equation}
as desired.

Thanks. I have a question: is $\partial F / \partial t = 0 - D' \cdot 1$? If it is true, it seems that $p$ is independent of $t$ so that $d S(p) /d t = 0$? Why is not $d S(p) / dt = S' \cdot dp/dt$?

But from another perspective, I derive the result. $0=dF = F_p dp + F_t dt$. That is, $0 = (S'-D')dp + (-D') dt$. Then, we get the desired $dp/dt$.

And back to my question, in my approach, $D'(p+t)=D'(p)$ correct, right?

@dchao: You have to careful with the prime notation of derivative. Let $x$ be the argument of the function $D$. Then, $$D'(p+t)=\frac{\mathrm dD(x)}{\mathrm dx}\Bigg\vert_{x=p+t}\quad\text{and}\quad D'(p)=\frac{\mathrm dD(x)}{\mathrm dx}\Bigg\vert_{x=p}.$$ The two are equal only if $t=0$. However, regardless of the value of $x$, $D'(x)$ is still same function defined as $\frac{\mathrm dD(x)}{\mathrm dx}$, which is probably what you meant by the equality of the derivatives.

@ And in my first comment, do we treat $p$ and $t$ independent when we deal with the partial derivatives like $\partial F / \partial t$?

Thank you very much. Yes. That is what I mean. If so, the statement $D'(p+t) \frac{d (p+t)}{d t}  \implies D'(p)(\frac{d p}{d t}+1)$ then is NOT correct?

@dchao: Yes to treat $p$ and $t$ as independent. The issue with your derivation is the abuse of notation: $p$ stands both for the argument of $D$ and $S$, and for a particular value of it. To avoid equivocation, let $p$ denote the argument and $p_0$ be the price at which the market equilibrates. Then,
$$
\frac{\partial D(p)}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}\Bigg\vert_{p=p_0+t}
= \frac{\partial D(p)}{\partial p}\Bigg\vert_{p=p_0+t}\frac{\partial (p_0+t)}{\partial t}
= D'(p_0+t)\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}+1\right)
$$

Thanks Herr K.! I am fully appreciated of your answer!
